# 550-5.7.1 message is likely unsolicited mail: rejected by gmail

Tags: email, postfix-mta, massmail

Each time I try to send emails using django send_mail() function. I got that:

> <<< 550-5.7.1  Our system has detected that this message is likely
>   unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to Gmail,
>   550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit
>   http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188131 for
>   more information.

But when I disable firewall, E-mails are going to SPAM. It's happening with Gmail only. I've ubuntu12.04 on my server and I've configured postfix.

Somewhere I read that it's because I didn't configure SPF Records and Reverse DNS records properly.
Currently, I've booked a temporary domain for sending emails. It's 'eemails.co.in'.

Can somebody please help me with configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me, I hadn't listed my server's IPv6 address in the SPF and google was rejecting email from my server over IPv6 but not IPv4.